# How to replace the leaflet-draw toolbar by buttons outside the mapDiv

Tags: leaflet, javascript, typescript

I did quit research to move the bar out of the leaflet map.
So what I did basically is that I created 3 buttons outside the map Div:

- Draw Polygon
- Delete
- Edit

I binded events to the draw Polygon with :

```
new L.Draw.Polygon(this.map, this.drawOptions.draw.polygon).enable();
```

But I couldn't do the same with Delete and Edit. I found in a forum that I could use:

```
new L.EditToolbar.Edit(map, {
            featureGroup: drawControl.options.featureGroup,
            selectedPathOptions: drawControl.options.edit.selectedPathOptions
        })
```

But I didn't find the typings for L.EditToolbar since I'm developing in Ts. Any Ideas ? I want also to remove the Toolbar from MapDiv without touching to the draw options since they are used by my Draw buttons.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality is there, it's just missing the types.
You can however write it like this:

```
let drawEditToolbar = new L["EditToolbar"].Edit(map, {
      featureGroup: drawControl.options.featureGroup,
      selectedPathOptions: drawControl.options.edit.selectedPathOptions
})
drawEditToolbar.enable()
```